# Inlining reference to class names in Java

Tags: java, compilation, classname

Let's consider the following statement:

```
final String s = mypackage.X.class.getName();
```

This will cause at runtime the loading of the class "mypackage.X"

I am looking for an alternative mechanism preventing the loading of this class (for instance inlining the class same at compile time).

Note, the straightforward approach consisting in replacing the overall statement by a string literal at source level does not work for what i am trying to achieve.

```
final String s = "mypackage.X";
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your last paragraph implies that you have some constraints that rule out certain possibilities, but nothing in your question indicates what those constraints might be. I find it hard to see how `mypackage.X.class.getName()` would serve your purposes (aside from causing the class to be loaded at runtime) yet `"mypackage.X"` would not.

Comment: I would just hard-code a `public static final String`, and then write a unit test to check it against `X.Class.getName()`. But what's so bad about the class being loaded? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @yshavit I guess he is using some classloader magic where you don't want autoloading of classes by the default class loader.

Answer (score 0):

If you /really/ need to avoid autoloading of classes by the default class loader (for example when user class loaders are in place) I would suggest using code generation.

A combination of [JCodeModel](http://blogtech.cardosi.net/2013/03/19/tutorial-java-codemodel-basics/) and a custom generator creating `public static final String` fields which you reference in the actual application source would seem sufficient.

Running the code generation as part of the `generate-sources` [maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html) ensures your references will stay up to date.